# Importing certificate in "Trusted Root Certificate" show up in "Personal Certificates" in Chrome/IE Cert Store

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate

I'm importing a .cer file to Chrome and Internet Explorer's certificate store.
When I'm importing it as "Trusted Root Certificate", it doesn't show any error but the certificate is found in "Personal Certificates" tab and not in "Trusted Root Certificates" tab.
Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you import a certificate that is not a Root Certificate (self-signed) or a CA certificate (CA:true basic extension is not set) and you select "Automatically select the certificate store based on the type of certificate" in the wizard, it will get imported as "Personal" or "Other People".

If you select "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities" while importing a non-root certificate, it says 'import was successful', but that certificate is not found anywhere in the wizard.

To check if a certificate is a root certificate or not, open the certificate (in Windows) and check the following:

1. 'Basic Constraints' must have 'Subject Type=CA'
2. 'Issuer' and 'Subject' field must be the same.

Hope this helps.